# how to parse nested JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have this complicated `JSON` which I want to parse it in `PHP` so that I can construct `dropdown`.

I want to construct dropdown as

```
<select name="select-box">
  <option value="apple">apple</option>
    <option value="banana">banana</option>
    <option value="kiwi">kiwi</option>
</select>
```

Right now I'm doing something like this which is not working

```
$json = '[
   {
      "class":"autocomplete",
      "name":"autocomplete-1481957691348-preview",
      "value":"there is nothing like me",
      "id":"autocomplete-1481957691348-preview",
      "type":"autocomplete",
      "tag":"INPUT"
   },
   {
      "class":"form-control",
      "name":"file-1481957721195-preview",
      "value":"",
      "id":"file-1481957721195-preview",
      "type":"file",
      "tag":"INPUT"
   },
   {
      "select-box":[
         {
            "selectName":"apple",
            "optionValue":"apple"
         },
         {
            "selectName":"banana",
            "optionValue":"banana"
         },
         {
            "selectName":"kiwi",
            "optionValue":"kiwi"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "class":"form-control",
      "name":"select-1481957826542-preview",
      "value":"jadu",
      "id":"select-1481957826542-preview",
      "type":"select",
      "tag":"SELECT"
   }
]';
```

My interest is this `object` from above `JSON`

```
{
          "select-box":[
             {
                "selectName":"apple",
                "optionValue":"apple"
             },
             {
                "selectName":"banana",
                "optionValue":"banana"
             },
             {
                "selectName":"kiwi",
                "optionValue":"kiwi"
             }
          ]
       }
```

But I don't want to `parse` this separately. Instead I want to parse the whole `JSON`

```
$arrData    =  json_decode($json);
  echo '<select name=''>';
    foreach($arrData as $key=>$objData){
      echo '<option value='".$objData->selectName."'>'.$objData->selectName.'</option>';
    }
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: What do you actually want to display in select tag?

Comment: i need to display 2nd json shown in the code but it's structure must be  like 1st json

Answer (score 1):

You could pass true as a second parameter to json_decode to return the data as arrays rather than objects. Then you could do the following:

```
// Decode all of the JSON string and store into variable
$decodedJson = json_decode($json, true);

// Retrieve only the select box related data from all of the decoded JSON data
$selectOptions = $decodedJson[2]['select-box'];

echo '<select name="">';

foreach($selectOptions as $selectOption) {
    echo '<option  value="'.$selectOption['selectName'].'">'.$selectOption['selectName'].'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
```

Also I've copied what you did where you have used the 'selectName' value on each option as the select box option value as well as name. Not sure if you want to change it to use the 'optionValue' value instead but I thought I'd raise it just in case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: but my json structure will change dynamically

Comment: In what sense? What issues will this cause?

Comment: this `$selectOptions = $decodedJson[2]['select-box'];` does not going to work for `dynamic` values

Comment: Will you always be looking for the array that contains the 'select-box' key?

Comment: this is not true always it will change every time .    do you have any solution for this kind?

Comment: Could you give an example of how it may change please?

Comment: any `name` it could take instead of `select-box`  like `fruit` ,`veg` and so on `dynamically`

Comment: If the 'selectName' and 'optionValue' keys always exist in these dynamically named select box arrays, they could be used to find the array, although that's not very nice.

Ideally, it would be best to keep the 'select-box' name the same all the time for consistency so that it can always be easily retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

You had some mistakes in your code like:

`echo '<select name=''>';`

should be:

`echo '<select name="">';`

You can convert the object into an array and parse it like this:

```
<?php 
 $json = '[
   {
      "class":"autocomplete",
      "name":"autocomplete-1481957691348-preview",
      "value":"there is nothing like me",
      "id":"autocomplete-1481957691348-preview",
      "type":"autocomplete",
      "tag":"INPUT"
   },
   {
      "class":"form-control",
      "name":"file-1481957721195-preview",
      "value":"",
      "id":"file-1481957721195-preview",
      "type":"file",
      "tag":"INPUT"
   },
   {
      "select-box":[
         {
            "selectName":"apple",
            "optionValue":"apple"
         },
         {
            "selectName":"banana",
            "optionValue":"banana"
         },
         {
            "selectName":"kiwi",
            "optionValue":"kiwi"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "class":"form-control",
      "name":"select-1481957826542-preview",
      "value":"jadu",
      "id":"select-1481957826542-preview",
      "type":"select",
      "tag":"SELECT"
   }
]';

$arrData    =  json_decode($json, true);
  echo '<select name="">';
    foreach($arrData as $objData){
        $for_select = $objData['select-box'];
        if(is_array($for_select)){
            foreach($for_select as $sel){
                echo '<option value="'.$sel['selectName'].'">'.$sel['selectName'].'</option>';
            }
        }
    }
  echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Single quotes can contain single quotes if they are escaped

Comment: Yes. But not in the OP's case. There's no need for escaping.

Comment: Of course but you stated `Single quotes can't contain single quotes.` that is false if you escape them

Comment: @Fabio, yes. So I've edited my answer a little bit. I hope it helps. I know it can look like `'<select name="' . $var .'">'`

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors with quotes and also you need to iterate in your nested json if it'not empty as follow

```
$arrData    =  json_decode($json);
echo '<select name="Select-box">';
foreach($arrData as $key=>$objData){
    if(!empty($objData->{'select-box'})) {
          foreach($objData->{'select-box'} as $select){

              echo '<option value="'.$select->optionValue.'">'.$select->selectName.'</option>';
          }
    }
}
echo '</select>';

//print
//<select name="select-box"><option value="apple">apple</option><option value="banana">banana</option><option value="kiwi">kiwi</option></select>
```

[live sample](http://ideone.com/lpvNNN)

If you don't know property name because it changes all the time you can do as follow

```
$arrData    =  json_decode($json);
echo '<select name="select-box">';
foreach($arrData as $key=>$objData){
    foreach($objData as $data) {
        if(is_array($data)) {
             foreach($data as $select){

                  echo '<option value="'.$select->optionValue.'">'.$select->selectName.'</option>';
             }
        }
    }
}
```

[live sample](http://ideone.com/vjWyNH)

Comment: if there is `dynamic` name for `select-box` in that scenario how can i do this.   for example instead of `select-box` it is `veg` then how can i  do it dynamically

Comment: @DilipG i've updated my answer as your request

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrData    =  json_decode($json, TRUE);
echo '<select name="">';
foreach($arrData as $key=>$objData){
  foreach($objData['select-box'] as $key2=>$objData2){
                 echo '<option value='.$objData2['optionValue'].'>'.$objData2['selectName'].'</option>';
  }
}
echo '</select>';
```